# How can I estimate a stars surface temperature, luminosity, radius, and lifetime only knowing it's solar mass and peak wavelength?

Tags: light, spectroscopy, spectra, luminosity, parallax

For example: if a 10 solar mass star emits light at a peak wavelength of λ = 300nm.

How can I calculate a stars surface temperature, luminosity, radius, and lifetime with this infomation?

Comment: You can figure out the temperature from the peak wavelength via Wien's law, and the star's lifespan from its mass (though that would be a very rough approximation). But the luminosity and radius are directly related to each other, and if one of them isn't already known, you've hit a dead end and are thus gonna have a hard time figuring out either.

Comment: You asked virtually the same a day ago... https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50226/how-can-i-calculate-the-luminosity-and-mass-of-a-star-only-knowing-its-peak-wav The answer still applies.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Astronomy SE! On this site, we usually require the question to show some prior research on the topic. What have you tried so far? What do you know about the topic? You can edit the question and add all the relevant information regarding your previous approach and why it failed. In this way it will be much easier to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and especially consider to edit your question in the light of the first paragraph titled 'search and research'